# Changing the text to another on hover, but only where I have the cursor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-canvas

I have a script made so that I can color the screen by moving the cursor. Now I would like this text to change to another text when you hover over it.

```js
function drawAnimation() {

    var yellowBrush = new Image();
    yellowBrush.src = 'wp-content/themes/starter/assets/images/brush-yellow.png';

    var drawCanvas = document.getElementById('hero__canvas');
    var canvasOverlay = document.getElementById('hero__headings');
    drawCanvas.width = drawCanvas.offsetWidth;
    drawCanvas.height = drawCanvas.offsetHeight;

    var ctx = drawCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

    var lastPoint = { x: 0, y: 0 },
        brushColor = yellowBrush;

    function distanceBetween(point1, point2) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point2.x - point1.x, 2) + Math.pow(point2.y - point1.y, 2));
    }
    function angleBetween(point1, point2) {
        return Math.atan2(point2.x - point1.x, point2.y - point1.y);
    }

    canvasOverlay.onmouseenter = function (e) {
        var offsetCheck = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - document.querySelector('.hero').clientHeight;
        var offset = offsetCheck > 0 ? offsetCheck : 0;
        lastPoint = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY + offset };
    };

    canvasOverlay.onmousemove = function (e) {
        var offsetCheck = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - document.querySelector('.hero').clientHeight;
        var offset = offsetCheck > 0 ? offsetCheck : 0;
        var currentPoint = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY + offset };
        var dist = distanceBetween(lastPoint, currentPoint);
        var angle = angleBetween(lastPoint, currentPoint);

        for (var i = 0; i < dist; i++) {
            x = lastPoint.x + (Math.sin(angle) * i) - 25;
            y = lastPoint.y + (Math.cos(angle) * i) - 105;
            ctx.drawImage(brushColor, x, y);
        }

        lastPoint = currentPoint;
    };

}


jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    drawAnimation();

});
```

```css
.brush::before {
      position: absolute;
      content: 'w marketingu';
      color: #ffdd00;
      font-size: 80px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .brush::after {
      position: absolute;
      content: 'w brandingu i digital';
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 80px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;

    }
```

```
<section
class="hero">
<div id="hero__animation_container" class="hero__animation_container">
    <canvas id="hero__canvas" class="hero__canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="hero__headings" class="hero__headings flex flex-col justify-center items-start">
        <img class="absolute top-0 -right-48 rotate-90 z-10" src="{{theme.link}}/assets/images/icons/dots-references.png" alt=""/>
        <div class="heading Container">
            <p class="">Wiemy, co działa</p>
            <p class="brush"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the effect I want to achieve in the attachment:

[image]

[image]

I have no idea how to go about it, I tried to combine something with mix-blend but it will not solve the problems. Anyone able to help?